# Is there a way to save the bixby log to an external file?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

I want to save the log recorded in the Bixby js file as an external file (txt). Is there any way?

Or can I save the debugged process as an external file?

In the JavaScript API supported by Bixby js, there is no API that saves as an external file, so I want to find a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in saving log to local files since Bixby is running in cloud. Also for security and privacy reasons Bixby is designed **not** to access storage on user's phone.

If the provided [console log in simulator](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/JavaScriptAPI/console) is not enough, a REST API is the easiest way to "save logs to external file". Any REST API that saves logs would do.

[Here](https://github.com/vboughner/bixby-capsule-with-aws) is a tutorial made by a brilliant Bixby developer on AWS. The interface of AWS may get changed a little bit over the past year, but the concepts and steps are all the same.